# Exclude pages from WordPress search result page

Tags: search, membership

How can I exclude pages for logged-in members from WordPress search results?

Comment: Have you already searched the site? What have you tried? Where did you fail? Please [edit] your post with your efforts. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add this to your child themes functions file using a code editor like Notepad++.

You will need to change the page I.D's in the code to your own.

**Exclude Specific Pages From Search Results**

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_pages_search_when_logged_in' );
function exclude_pages_search_when_logged_in($query) {
    if ( $query->is_search && is_user_logged_in() )
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ) ); 

    return $query;
}
```

**Exclude All Pages From Search Results**

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','exclude_all_pages_search');
function exclude_all_pages_search($query) {
    if (
        ! is_admin()
        && $query->is_main_query()
        && $query->is_search
        && is_user_logged_in()
    )
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'post' );
}
```

Source http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Exclude_Pages_from_Search_Results

Comment: You might need the `$query->is_main_query()` check when excluding a specific page too.

Comment: i also wanted more than only posts.  `$query->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'OTHER_POSTTYPE' ) );`

Comment: Can someone please comment the second function so I can see what each part does. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code to your theme’s functions.php file

it's perfectly working on my client's site.

```
//Exclude all except post from WordPress Search

if (!is_admin()) {
    function wse_search_filter($query) {
        if ($query->is_search) {
            $query->set('post_type', 'post');
        }
        return $query;
    }
    add_filter('pre_get_posts','wse_search_filter');
}
```

Comment: How is this different / better than the posted & accepted answer?

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code on your theme `functions.php`. Note that I have not tested this.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'SearchFilter' );
function SearchFilter( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 ) );
    }

    return $query;
}
```

I get the idea from [WPBeginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-limit-search-results-for-specific-post-types-in-wordpress/).

<sup>Terms of use while this was written: "(...) You are welcome to reference our snippets and hacks on your own blogs/sites as long as you give us full credit from that article.</sup>